# How can I ask a professor about funding for Master?

Tags: masters, etiquette, funding, email, projects

I am looking for a master’s position. I emailed a professor, and we arranged a meeting on Skype, where he said that he would assess my knowledge and he told me that he will tell me the result afterward (whether apply or not). Now I think he likes to have me as a student. I performed well, and he forwarded my email to his Ph.D. students told them that I would like to work in this field.

How can I ask the professor about the possibility of applying and funding? I'm not a native speaker, and I have anxiety about being rude.

I was admitted to some European universities, but I would like to go to this particular university, and I need to decide and to know about the future. I was admitted in fall 2017 (Europe), but this particular university starts in winter 2018, so I need to decide earlier. If I can't decide earlier, I will miss European universities, which is undesirable.

Could you please give me a piece of advice and/or a template for a letter? How can I ask about funding and the possibility of applying politely?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Starting point: Dear Prof. X, Thank you for the recent Skype conversation, and the friendly email.  Is it okay for me to go ahead and send my application?  Also, can you clarify for me, please, what prospects will there be for funding?  Thank you.  Sincerely, your name.

Comment: 1) If you have offers from other universities you might want to mention this so they know that you have a time limit. 2) Be aware that funding for masters students is generally less available than funding for PhD students.

Comment: Did they actually say that they want you as a student? Because admitting that from them offering to meet and asking their PhD students for thoughts (one of them might potentially be involved in supervising you) is a little early. Did you already have the meeting on Skype? It is not clear to me in what part of the process you currently are.

Comment: my professor told me, go ahead with your application.and he will get funding from sponsors. But I feel anxiety about taking me from the commit. I have been accepted from some universities for the fall semester but this particular university will take me in the winter semester. what can I do about it?

Comment: It seems like you succeeded - maybe you can post an answer to your own question, then?

Comment: @rg_software I like the idea of fixing formatting errors in posts here but not in four year old questions. That just puts them at the top of the page. That wastes the time of people (like me) who then look at them.

Comment: @Ethan Bolker, agreed. This post just popped up in my search box, edited without much thinking.